# How to create a Renderscript ScriptGroup from the following ScriptIntrinsics?

Tags: android, renderscript

I have three script intrinsics that I would like to group together in a RenderScript ScriptGroup so as to take advantage of any performance gains associated with the grouping.

I understand that in a ScriptGroup you have to set the inputs of each script from the output of another. In the case of a Blur intrinsic, how is this done? For example, how can I wire the second parameter of blend1 to the first parameter of blend2? Also, how can I wire the first parameter in blend1 to the blur?

```
blend1.forEachSrcOver(inAllocation, pass2ColorAllocation);

blur.forEach(inAllocation);

blend2.forEachSrcOver(pass2ColorAllocation, inAllocation);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to use the `getKernelID` calls in the individual intrinsics for this.

in this case, it doesn't actually matter much--there's not a performance advantage from using intrinsics in ScriptGroups versus calling them individually.